# R: Subtract one value from some rows in multiple columns and another value from other rows in the same columns based on condition in R|

Tags: r

Beginner R programmer here.

I have 73 variables, 70 with questions (named Q1:Q72) and a grouping variable ("Color") with values "red" or "blue". If the participant (1 participant/row) is in group "red" they have values between 5 and 76 in columns Q1:Q76. If they are in group "blue" they have values between 77 and 148 in columns. However, I want all answers to be between 1 and 72. That is, I want to subtract 76 from Q1:Q72 **if** the participant is in group "blue" and subtract 4 from Q1:Q72 **if** participant is in group "red".

So far, my solution has been to split the df into two new df ("dfBlue" and "dfRed"), then subtract 5 from "dfRed" and subtract 76 from "dfBlue" and finally merge the two new dataframes.

Can someone help me with a more elegant solution where no new dataframe is needed?

Thanks!!

df:

| Color | Q1 | Q2 | ... | Q72 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 5 | 46 | ... | 32 |
| blue | 107 | 85 | ... | 94 |
| blue | 83 | 145 | ... | 128 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| red | 47 | 34 | ... | 74 |

How I want it to be:

| Color | Q1 | Q2 | ... | Q72 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 42 | ... | 28 |
| blue | 31 | 9 | ... | 18 |
| blue | 7 | 69 | ... | 52 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| red | 43 | 30 | ... | 70 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` option:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~if_else(Color == "red", .x - 4, .x - 76)))
#  Color Q1 Q2 Q72
#1   red  1 42  28
#2  blue 31  9  18
#3  blue  7 69  52
#4   red 43 30  70
```

PS. Please note the typo in your expected output: row 3, Q72 should be 128 - 76 = <s>56</s> 52.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <-read.table(text = "Color   Q1  Q2  Q72
red 5   46  32
blue    107 85  94
blue    83  145 128
red 47  34  74", header = T)
```